Are there any latest new sfm out there that are similar to Agisoft Metashape?
Are there any new latest news about sfm aka (Structure in Motion) that can perform old aerial photos from 30's to 50's ?
My agency has revoked it due to the Ukraine and Russia situation. Yes I am upset but are out of my hands .
I have been working a lot of old 30's aerial photos using Metahape and it is a top notch software;however I don't know if there are any latest new one come out similar to it.
I know a co-worker at my agency has been looking for and testing a several products and found nothing compare to it.
Currently I am not working on it so my job returns to GIS Specialist and perform other jobs
